# Where is the pspice "output file"?

Tags: pspice, orcad, cadence

This is the error message when trying to run a simulation for one of my models

```
--------------- INFO(ORPROBE-3209): Simulation Profile: SCHEMATIC1-bias ---------------
INFO(ORPROBE-3183): Simulation running...
** Profile: "SCHEMATIC1-bias" [ c:\users\softwareengineer\desktop\musical tesla coil\orcad\gate driver\gate driver-pspicefiles\sche
Reading and checking circuit
ERROR(ORPSIM-16363): Command invalid in subcircuit
Circuit has errors ... run aborted
See output file for details
INFO(ORPROBE-3188): Simulation aborted
```

Note the "See output file for details". I DO NOT KNOW WHERE IT IS. AND I CANT FIND OUT WHERE IT IS DESPITE GOOGLING IT FOR THE LAST HOUR.
Can someone please tell me where this output file is so i can maybe have a meaningful error message which tells me what is wrong.
I myself am a software developer and if i designed it, it would give a file name, line number, index in line and snippet too with the error. You wouldn't even need to open some hidden error file because it would print the error to the damn console. Maybe not everyone has common sense like I do I don't know but this is driving me nuts.

All i want is a meaningful error message so i can begin to work out what is wrong with my model.

Comment: Unfortunatly, many EDA CAD tools come from ages long past and have interfaces that are still stuck in the 90's  (I'm looking at you, Cadence). Try checking your simulators settings. Additionally, it can be helpfull to see if you spot any files that change when you run this simulation, most operating systems can give you that information in one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this problem. In the simulation window, click view on the top toolbar and in the drop down menu, select Output File.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could solve it in the following way:

Click in:
(Upper Toolbar) "Pspice"---"Edit Simulation Profile"
Then click in:
"General". Here you will see a box with the name "Output".

You just need to make sure that the folder name, where the Output file is written, is the same as the one for the "SCHEMATIC" folder of the project.

For example in my case, my "SCHEMATIC" is in the folder:
`C:\Users\Orcad Simulaciones\Circuito_1-PSpiceFiles\SCHEMATIC1`

And the output file "Prueba_1.out" is therefore in:
`C:\Users\Orcad Simulaciones\circuito_1-PSpiceFiles\SCHEMATIC1\`
`Prueba_1\Prueba_1.out`

Hope it helps!